# How do I fix my comparison test in Python?

Tags: python, comparison-operators

Newbie to python and stackoverflow.
Apologies if I did not format my question correctly.

I am trying to simulate an app for fish conservation.
The user should get a message to throw the Winter Flounder back if it is more that 12 inches long; they can keep it if it is less than or equal to 12 inches long.

I know my error is the <=, but am not sure how to fix it.

[Github](https://github.com/flmsics/stackoverflow/blob/main/forKeeps.py) link to whole code.

Thank you.

```
    if fishLength ['Winter Flounder'] <= maxFishLength['Winter Flounder']:
```

```
#What is the maximum length of the fish?
#Use the dictionary module {}
maxFishLength = {
        "Acadian Redfish" : math.inf,
        "Winter Flounder" : 12
    }

fishTally = {
        "Acadian Redfish" : 0,
        "Winter Flounder" : 0
    }



gameOver = False
while not gameOver:
    print("possession limits")
    print(possessionLimit)
    print("This is the number of fish you have caught")
    print(fishTally)
    print("maximum length allowed for fish")
    print(maxFishLength)

    fishLength = input ('How long is the fish you caught (inches)?: ') 

    print('Alewife (a), Acadian Redfish (ar), Windowpane Flounder (wf) (or e to exit):')
    item = input('Can I keep the fish? Type the one or two-letter code to find out: ')
    if item == 'e':
        gameOver = True
    elif item == 'a':
        print("You are going to have to throw this one back. Try Again.")
    elif item =='ar':
        print('You can keep this fish!')
        fishTally['Acadian Redfish']+=1
    elif item == 'wf':
        print('Your fish is ', fishLength, ' long')
        if fishTally['Winter Flounder'] < possessionLimit["Winter Flounder"]:
            if fishLength ['Winter Flounder'] <= maxFishLength['Winter Flounder']:
                print() 
                print('You can keep this fish!')
                fishTally['Winter Flounder'] +=1
            else:
                print('You have the incorrect fish length')
                
        else:
            print('You have caught your limit')
    print()
```

Comment: Your github link doesn't work. Please post a [mcve] here, not at another site.

Comment: The `<=` condition is correct if you want to say that it's OK. Are you sure the variables are correct?

Comment: Barmar, thanks for responding. So, we cannot post code via a link? I think my github was set to private. Will try and figure out how to make it public. No, I am not sure the variables are correct  . . . I posted the relevant code from github.

Comment: including the error you are getting would be enormously helpful, for example I think in this case the error is probably `TypeError: string indices must be integers` which gives a very good idea of what is probably wrong

Comment: Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, thank you for responding. Here is the error: if fishLength ['Winter Flounder'] <= maxFishLength['Winter Flounder']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers . . .  just like you said; I will research the fix - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`fishLength` is not a dictionary, so you can't use `fishLength['Winter Flounder']`. You need to convert it to a number and compare that.

```
if float(fishLength) <= maxFishLength['Winter Flounder']:
```

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. I will try that.